# Html5 Canvas game - black screen on Android devices after browser is run on the background

Tags: android, html5-canvas, createjs

as per title, I've made this html5 canvas game by using the toolkit for Createjs with Flash.

It works fine on iPad and iPhone, but my QA tester found a very strange bug on Android: if you hide the browser (not close it, but simply send it on background), when you reopen it the game will either freeze or show a black screen, depending if it's in landscape/portrait mode.

I've uploaded a short version of the game - there is only the main menu, but that should be enough to test the bug - at the following link:
http://upload.id.net/view/zip/52d5d18c9f0a188b

Can anybody please help me with this, as I'm totally oblivious to why this is happening..?
I don't have an android device to test it myself, so there's that, too :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload the game first (not running from phone memory card) and see if the problem persist. I'm not sure about this but i strongly believe that it has something to do with security in chrome. Good luck

Comment: Humm, the problem persists. I think it has to do with how I handle the orientation - I've put a message that blocks the game when the device is not in landscape mode, and I think it's misworking on Android when the browser goes into the background.

And yet, I don't know *what*'s causing it.

Thanks, though I don't feel too lucky right now :D